# Zooming in a lot without having 3D objects disappear in the Unity Editor

Tags: unity, interface, collider

I'm editing the 2D colliders on some objects of my game, and I need them to be very accurate, so I'm zooming in a lot. Problem is, since my objects are 3D graphically, when I zoom in a lot they disappear and I can' t just tap "2D" in the Scene view to fix this. Pressing "F" on the whole object doesn't help a lot, since I have an empty parent with the mesh and colliders as separate objects, and when I select the collider to edit it I only see the collider anyway. Does anyone have any clue on how to proceed?

Comment: Have you tried using "F" key on the object whose collider you're editing?

Comment: That only keeps the selected object from disappearing, if I have to edit the collider which is on a separate GameObject from the mesh, but keeping the mesh in sight, the mesh will disappear.

Comment: you could try this : Select the collider and lock the inspector window -> now select both collider and mesh object and then press "F" and see if that helps.